# Joomla php how to check if user is viewing specific page

Tags: php, joomla

I want to add a facebook plugin to a specific joomla page. To check if the user is viewing the homepage i use the following:

```
<?php
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

I don't know how this code works, but i think the 'getDefault() method return me the homepage url. Now i want to do the same, not for the frontPage but for a specific page, lets say:

```
www.myDomain.com/contactos
```

How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You an get current `menu_id` & `menu_name` respectively like this:

`$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;`

`$currentMenuName = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name ;`

Comment: $currentMenuName = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name ; this worked for me not the other one

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
$currentMenuName = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->name ;
```